# Postgresql 9.1 enum type ordering doesn't work like I expect

Tags: postgresql, enums, postgresql-9.1

I've got an enum type that I've become interested in ordering in a particular way. I've written and run the SQL to impose a new ordering by sorting the labels (externally) by my new criteria and then updating the `enumsortorder` for all the values.

It doesn't work. I've verified that I've satisfied the (really weird) rule that the sort ordering feature works only on enum types with even oids; my oid for this type is even (58016). As far as I can tell, the ordering being imposed when I `ORDER BY` the enum column is exactly the same as what it was before.

Is there something else I need to do in order to make this work? The PostgreSQL documentation makes me think it should work.

Comment: You need odd oid, not even. *That is, if two even OIDs belong to the same enum type, the smaller OID must have the smaller enumsortorder value. Odd-numbered OID values need bear no relationship to the sort order.* -- you could try to add a new value to the enum with `ALTER TYPE name ADD VALUE new_enum_value [ { BEFORE | AFTER } existing_enum_value ]` and see if the ordering is changed (this is new feature in 9.1, thats why the *odd* rule)

Comment: @pozs I read that part of the documentation but it didn't really make much sense. How do I have control over the oid values? Can I request or make new oid values for the existing enums?

Comment: Not really, but you can try to add a new value to it (I never checked if the oids change or not). If not, I think your only option is to drop & recreate the enum. (There is no explicit re-ordering technique, the `enumsortorder` column is mainly for new values).

Comment: @pozs OK I think I understand - I had a misimpression of the way the whole thing works. I bet that the innards use the "odd oid" trick in order to make the "before" and "after" type alterations work, so those table entries get odd oids (if necessary). Or something like that. I'll just re-create the type.  Thanks for the help; if you want some rep feel free to type in an answer.

Comment: yes that's also what i think it does. But there's not much of documentation about it, and re-creating the type is just a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Even oids have fixed ordering](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalog-pg-enum.html) so you can't reorder them by modifying the pg-enum system table.

you're going to have to replace the existing enum with a new enum type.  this means

1. Creating a new enum type
2. Dropping any relationships that use the enum.
3. Update the columns to the new type using something like

   `ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar 
        TYPE TO new_enum_type 
        USING (bar::text)::new_enum_type;`

   Here the cast to text matches the new enum values to the old enum    values by their name.
4. Finally you need to recreate all the dropped relationships.

If needed you can run all this DML inside a transaction block.

Expect it to be slow if you have lots of data as it's rewriting whole
tables

Comment: Thanks, this is what I figured out was the way to do what I wanted.